# Best way to handle non-string arguments to built-in functions whose args are non-nullable

Tags: php

PHP 8.1 says below is deprecated:

> Passing null to non-nullable parameters of built-in functions

I am trying to figure out how best to handle this.  Often the data I get back from our Oracle database contains nulls (partly due to the flags used to retrieve the records but that's an aside).  So far, the simplest option has been to use the null-coalescing operator to default to an empty string if the field is null.  I'm not sure if that's the best/most proper way to handle this though.  Several examples involve calling `strtotime()` on a timestamp field.  I can certainly use my approach above which will cause `strtotime()` to return `false`.  However, I speculate whether I instead should be validating ahead and avoid calling the built-in function if the argument is null.  Does it matter much at all?

Comment: You've answered your own question. You should certainly be validating it before hand. Or possibly not running it at all if its not needed due to whats returned from the DB. Theres a few reasons why this is not allowed. its a total waste of resources and possible exploitation.

Comment: Although not an answer, there is [some discussion](https://externals.io/message/116752) and a [draft RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/allow_null) related to this. If you feel strongly that this is a burden or blocker for upgrading, it might be worth weighing in on it. Otherwise, what you are doing is the current recommended path.

Comment: @Wakka I asked what would be the recommended method.  Both that I offered work and achieve the same end result.  Either default the field to an empty string or validate the field is `!empty()` and also `is_string()` ahead of time.  Another option is to use `strval()` or the `(string)` cast I suppose since null is converted to an empty string.  I just want to know what is best.

Comment: @tczx3 " I speculate whether I instead should be validating ahead and avoid calling the built-in function if the argument is null" << This

Comment: Thank you for clearing up your comment.